# Jenkins-trigger- BitBucket webhook Network error issue

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I am having issues with my Jenkins build please help I am very new to this technology. Currently when I commit any changes on the development branch and merge that branch with the staging branch the build should automatically trigger on Jenkins but for some reason it doesn’t do that I have to manually run a job on Jenkins and when I check the webhook details on my BitBucket repo it show Network error as you can see the error message in the pictures below. What can be the cause of this issue? please help thanks.

If anyone one that are expert on Jenkins please email me mrwonder2018@gmail.com and I can do screen share video call to fix it.

SCM : BitBucket
CI/CD : Jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak7ly.jpg)

Comment: Have you opened 8080 port on your jenkins server?